# MPDF background-image is too small

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using a background image in a div, but the pdf shows the image shrunken to about 50%.  Is there a setting I'm missing?  I tried adjusting the dpi, but it didn't help.

```
<div style="background-image: url(https://rooster/proxy.php?file=1Q73u872H%2Fi%2Fc1.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 37px 26px; height:365px; width:456px; background-size:419px 339px;"></div>
```

Comment: I found that if I set the width and height to 100% it works, when set to pixels it doesn't.